# Error on JQuery Ajax Cross Domain Java Web Service call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting error while making a webservice call using JQuery Ajax on cross domain.

My JQuery code is

```
window.myCallback = function(data) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
};

$("#submit").click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url:  "http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
  });
});
```

My server code is java web service

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@Path("/users")
public class UserDetails {

  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response getUserDetails(){
      User user = new User("sam","smith","abc123","xyz");
      ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(200).entity(user);
      return rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
 "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*").build();
  }
}
```

Error:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: You are not getting a JSONP response, you are getting JSON - JSONP will be application/javascript

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ArashKazemi see the picture

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a JSONP response, you are getting JSON - JSONP will be mime type `application/javascript`

Your application needs to return (in PHP, you need to find out what `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSONP` looks like for your JAVA - possibly here [REST - Jersey -Providing Cross Site Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261640/rest-jersey-providing-cross-site-access)

```
header("content-type: application/javascript");
echo $callback.'({"...":"..."})';
```

and not

```
header("content-type: application/json");
echo '{"...":"..."}';
```

So for client side to consume JSON, try

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event){ // better than click a submit
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $.getJSON("yourserverprocess",myCallback);
});
```

Comment: Do i need to make changes on server side or client side?

Comment: Either. They have to match. If you send JSONP the client seems ok, if you send JSON, you need to change the client

Comment: What changes need to make if i opt to make changes on client end?